# hierarchical k-means clustering for SIFT vectors

Tags: cluster-analysis, hierarchical-data, sift, descriptor, object-recognition

All

I am searching for applying the same approach of David Nister and Henrik Stewenius in http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~bagon/CVspring07/files/scalable.pdf

In this paper, they use a high number of SIFT vectors (128-D) as input to a hierarchical k-means clustering to construct a hierarchical visual vocabulary tree.

Does any one know any good library that i can use to do this clustering?

Ps: the number of input SIFT descriptors is high (70,000,000) and i want that result will be a vocabulary tree with 1,000,000 leaf nodes.

thanks very much.
regards.

Answer (score 2):

The ClusterQuantiser tool in [OpenIMAJ](http://www.openimaj.org) should be able to do this if the data is in a supported format. If the tool can't work with your data out of the box, then you could write a driver for the `org.openimaj.ml.clustering.kmeans.HierarchicalByteKMeans` class (in the svn trunk version) or the `org.openimaj.ml.clustering.kmeans.HByteKMeans` class in the 1.0.5 release. Both versions of the class support streaming data from disk, so you don't need to hold all the features in memory!

For completeness, [vlfeat](http://www.vlfeat.org) also has a hierarchical k-means implementation, but I'm not sure how much it scales.

From practical experience, you might also consider sampling the features before clustering. I'm not sure that you'll get much benefit from clustering them all.

Comment: Jon, Thank you. I just come across OpenIMAJ one week ago when i do random search with google. I will study it and see what it can offer.